# AdMob dependencies

Tags: android, admob, android-appcompat

Does the Android AdMob library *require* the AppCompat library?

Quoth [Google](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start):

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    }
```

I commented out the `appcompat` line and it *built* ok...

Comment: here is and explanation of this appcompat library: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it does not require the AppCompat library**. The very same link to documentation that you provided in your question ([this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)) shows that only `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'` is required. The rest including appcompat library is grayed out on that documentation page. It is put there just to give an idea of how the `build.gradle` file looks like.

[image]

Comment: thanks. I think you may be right that appcompat is not required, but I disagree with your reasoning. Google's excellent use of font weight and color is there for the reason you describe: "to give an idea of how the build.gradle file looks like." OK. But the fact that some code is "grayed" clearly doesn't indicate that the code is not required. Otherwise, the "dependencies" line wouldn't be required either. I will accept an answer that illuminates the actual dependencies. Meantime, an upvote for you, and also I'll say that the app seems to be running, though I haven't yet tested the ads.

Comment: That's silly... The dependencies tag or header line is not optional. It has to be there. Adding the appcompat dependency is optional. It is understood.